# Will a checkbox form work in most email clients?

Tags: email, html-email

I would like to send a transactional email that contains a checkbox form. Think of it like this:

Which of the following would you like?

[ ] Item 1

[ ] Item 2

[ ] Item 3

[ ] Item 4

[Submit]

Would a HTML form work with most email clients, like Gmail, Outlook, iPhone, etc? Or is there some reason it would get blocked or considered as spam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form support is sporadic at best in emails. Additionally, when they are supported they are also accompanied by a lot of scary warnings. It's generally recommended you link to a landing page where the user can fill out a form.

Support info: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/forms/